# SQL Server Agent in my Web Farm

Tags: 2010, sql-server

Im trying to setup some scheduling in my SharePoint 2010 Farm, where I have 2 WFE's and 1 DB server.

In attempting to setup a scheduled task, I received the error "The SQL Agent service is not running. This operation requires the SQL Agent service".

My question: Where do I need to configure the SQL Agent service?  Would that be on my DB server?  Or do I need to install the basic services on every WFE and enable the SQL service there?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Agent runs on the SQL Server, and manages the scheduling of jobs for SQL. You should see it in Services on the server. Start it up there, or you can start it up via SQL Server Management Studio.

HTH

Comment: Thanks David, just wanted to make sure it wasnt anything more complicated than this :)